# Problem with the caption of an inserted image

Tags: graphics

I consider an image:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=80mm]{AMAM_AMPM.eps}
\caption{Nonlinear characteristics of a TWTA for a single-tone excitation at 10.7 GHz.}
\label{Fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now, there are several things not the way I want them to be:

- The description is in german (Abbildung 1:) , but I want it to be english (figure 1:). Is it enough to just put `\usepackage [ngerman, english]{babel}`?
- The title of my figure is so long that it covers two lines. Can I somehow make these two lines be underneath each other without regarding the "Abbildung 1:" ?
- I want the figure to appear on the top of the next page. It is working now, I just want to make sure it's not just working by chance. I mean, is [t] enough?

Comment: Please one question per question! BTW: The tag `graphics` seems to be completely wrong. The questions are about figures, captions and language or `babel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following MWE answer on all your questions (I assume that for unknown reason you still need `ngerman` babel; if not, than delete it from babels' options):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}% <-- added option "english"
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}

\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}% <-- added
\usepackage{placeins}            % <-- added   
% only for test purposes
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\FloatBarrier % <-- added, image can not be before this line
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=80mm]{AMAM_AMPM.eps}
    \caption{Nonlinear characteristics of a TWTA for a single-tone excitation at 10.7 GHz.}
\label{Fig:1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot on it ... added now

Comment: Why not `ngerman` removed?

Comment: @Schweinebacke, good question. I assume, that other text is in German (if not, I do not understand why OP select this babel on the first place). It should not be difficult to remove it, if it is not used.

Comment: Yes, question is quite unclear. It is also not clear, why the figure has been placed before the place it should be printed. Maybe the real question is how to place the figure after it has been referenced, so `flafter` would be a better solution. Maybe not.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. I left out the packages following %only for test purposes and also the \lipsum and \FloatBarrier command, since I neither understand the purpose of them nor do I think I need them. You probably just included this for demonstration purposes.

Comment: See *Schweinebacke * comments. As I understand your problem, the `\FloatBarrier` is essential to have images on the top of the next page. If this is not the case, than his comment solve the problem. Please, edit your question and clarify your problem.